# Problems setting up a docker based InfluxDB/Grafana network

Tags: docker, grafana, influxdb, docker-for-windows

My intention is to use Windows Docker to deploy an InfluxDB 2.0.8 database and link to it via a self-hosted Grafana instance on the same docker network.

To do so, I've done the below steps:

1. Start the network, InfluxDB and Grafana via below:

```
docker network create influxdb
docker run -d --net=influxdb --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
docker run -d --net=influxdb --name=influxdb -p 8086:8086 --volume C:/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb2 influxdb:2.0.8
```

2. Open http://localhost:8086 to set up the basics. Via the InfluxDB UI get the below details:

- Org ID (from the About page)
- Token (from the Token page, using the already generated one)
- Default bucket (the bucket I created)
- URL (http://localhost:8086)

3. I then go to Grafana via localhost:3000 and add an InfluxDB data storage (Flux) and enter the above details. However, when I test it, I get an "Error reading InfluxDB". In the console, I get the below error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/ds/query 400 (Bad Request)
{refId: 'test', message: 'Post "http://localhost:8086/api/v2/query?org=35e0f…l tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: connect: connection refused'}
```

Any idea what might be missing in the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think another way to access influx from grafana would be accessing it from container name:
setup influxdb data source as:
influxdb:8086

Answer (score 3):

1. Run command `docker network inspect influxdb`. There you can find IP in `Gateway` and use it.
2. Or use by your container name:

```
http://influxdb:8086/...
```

Also I recommend read [Official Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/) about Docker network communications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Grafana on docker and trying to connect to InfluxDB on your local.
Try using the IP address of your PC/server on your network .

on Linux / MacOs use

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
```

Also Turn off Basic Auth and use your Organization and Token if you are using InfluxDB 2x versions

If you are using docker-compose script . refer to this comment

[When Using Docker-Compose](https://community.grafana.com/t/connection-refused-error-reading-buckets/71749/17#:%7E:text=3%20months%20later-,mxwink,-Apr%2010)